# Unable to deploy DB from local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to export a DB from my local SQL Server to Azure SQL.

So far I've tried

`Tasks` > `Deploy Database to Windows Azure SQL Database`

I then connect to the Azure DB, give the new DB a name and then let it run.

However, it fails with the message

> A project which specifies Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12 (Preview) as the target platform cannot be published to Microsoft Azure SQL Database.

Having followed [this page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-plan-prepare-upgrade/), I'm *pretty sure* that I have the latest of whatever I need on my local.

So what am I missing? How do I get a DB from a local instance of SQL Server to Azure SQL?

Comment: As it still in preview, you'd better get in touch with Azure Support Team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are several means to upload a local DB to Azure, I found that all but one of these fails with the same error message.

The one which worked is the *[SQL Database Migration Wizard](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/)*.